# TF270015: 'pdbstr.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '-1'. See the build logs for more details

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild

I'm getting this error when trying to build our VS2015 solution on a Team Foundation Server 2012. We have other solutions that work correct, this is the only one giving the error.

```
TF270015: 'pdbstr.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '-1'. See the build logs for more details.
pdbstr.exe: error 0x7e loading mspdb60.dll
```

Please Help! Thank you.

Comment: When I took a closer look to the log I noticed this: <InformationField Name="Message" Value="pdbstr.exe: error 0x7e loading mspdb60.dll" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've placed the mspdb60.dll in the droplocation and now the error does not occur anymore.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The exit code is not enough to troubleshoot the issue. Could you provide detailed error messages in TFS build log?

To narrow down your issue, please try below steps:

1. Looking at the Windows Event Log to check whether there are some
   info related to   this error
2. You can do a test to use VS directly to build your solution file
   both in local and in TFS build agent.
3. This support to be a environment issue, please also make sure there
   are `pdbstr.exe` on the build server and the same with local machine.

Comment: 1. In the Windows Event Log is no entry regarding this issue. 2. How can I do this? 3. The pdbstr version are the same.

Comment: Are there anymore suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any other versions of VS on your build machine?  can you find mspdb60.dll on your machine?  Do you have another build controller or agent you can try?